# Can Tukey HSD groups be of slightly different sizes?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, tukey-hsd-test

In my Tukey HSD I have some groups with 5 data points, and some groups with 6 data points. Is this allowed with Tukey HSD? The only option would be to remove 1 data point from some groups, and that is bad practice, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Tukey HSD test for unequal sample sizes is **Tukey-Kramer test**, I propose you check this one out! But yeah, just removing data for no 'good' reason, is almost always bad practice.